# Run a script on Spark Cluster with docker containers

Tags: docker, apache-spark, graph, partitioning

I have followed the Bitnami Apache Spark guide to be able to launch a Spark Cluster with one master and a couple of workers with docker containers and it works fine. Now, I want to run a Scala script on these containers. I have a road network graphs, on which I run a Pregel algorithm.

I have no problem setting up the containers, but I struggle on how to deploy the application on the containers. The graph is partitioned and my idea is that when running the application, the different partitions will be divided between the containers.

I've cloned the Bitnami Apache Spark repo and is running IntelliJ.

Where do I define how to deploy the application? In one guide, a SparkSession is setup where you define the SPARK_MASTER_URL and SPARK_DRIVER_HOST, but when I try this method I get the following error "*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException*" and it's pointing to the "*SparkSession.builder.config(conf = conf).getOrCreate()*" line in my getSparkSession function.

I attach the getSparkSesson and a snip from the main script.

```js
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

import scala.util.Properties

object RepeatedPregelUtils {

  def getSparkSessions(appName: String): SparkSession = {

    val conf = new SparkConf

    conf.set("spark.master", Properties.envOrElse("SPARK_MASTER_URL", "spark://spark-master:7077"))
    conf.set("spark.driver.host", Properties.envOrElse("SPARK_DRIVER_HOST", "local[*]"))
    conf.set("spark.submit.deployMode", "client")
    conf.set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "0.0.0.0")

    conf.set("spark.app.name", appName)

    SparkSession.builder.config(conf = conf).getOrCreate()
  }
}
```

And here is where I use the getSparkSession-function:

```js
  def loadNetwork(): Graph[String,Double] = {

    val spark: SparkSession = RepeatedPregelUtils.getSparkSessions("RepeatedRun")
    var csvFile = spark.read.csv("src/main/scala/NewUpdatedSwedenNetwork.csv")
    for (i <- 1 until csvFile.columns.length) {
      csvFile = csvFile.withColumnRenamed(csvFile.columns(i), csvFile.head()(i).toString)
    }
    csvFile = csvFile.withColumnRenamed(csvFile.columns(0), "null")
    val first_row = csvFile.first()
    csvFile = csvFile.filter(row => row != first_row)

    csvFile = csvFile.filter(col("from_y") < 55.7 && col("from_y") > 55.379 && col("from_x") > 11.975 && col("from_x") < 14.46)
    val edges: RDD[Edge[Double]] = csvFile.repartition(2)
      .select("from_id", "to_id", "mean_time").rdd.map(line => Edge(line.getAs("from_id").toString.toLong, line.getAs("to_id").toString.toLong, line.getAs("mean_time").toString.toFloat))
    val graph = Graph.fromEdges(edges, "defaultname")
    return graph
  }
```

I'm very new to all this so I may be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I've changed a lot of things in my code and it come down to two things:

1. Setting master-url in the SparkSession to spark://localhost:7077 worked for me
2. Setting same version of scala in IDE and Docker container. Appereantly, after a lot of googling, BitnamiDocker uses Spark version 2.12.

These changes worked for me!